# Where is the length of an array located in terms of memory layout?

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, memory, assembly

For example, given the following cases:

```
uint[3] memory arr;
uint[] memory arr = new uint[](3);
```

Suppose I try to access `arr` from within an `assembly` block (using `mload`, for example).

Where (relatively to `arr`) is the value of `arr.length` located, and where are the entries located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I ran a simple test and found out that in a dynamic array, the length of the array is located at the first 32 bytes relatively to the beginning of the array:

**Smart Contract:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract MyContract {
    function read1() external pure returns (uint a, uint b, uint c) {
        uint[3] memory arr;
        arr[0] = 111;
        arr[1] = 222;
        arr[2] = 333;
        assembly {
            a := mload(add(arr,  0))
            b := mload(add(arr, 32))
            c := mload(add(arr, 64))
        }
    }

    function read2() external pure returns (uint a, uint b, uint c) {
        uint[] memory arr = new uint[](3);
        arr[0] = 444;
        arr[1] = 555;
        arr[2] = 666;
        assembly {
            a := mload(add(arr,  0))
            b := mload(add(arr, 32))
            c := mload(add(arr, 64))
        }
    }
}
```

**Truffle Test:**

```
contract("MyContract", function(accounts) {
    it("test", async function() {
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        await test(myContract.read1);
        await test(myContract.read2);
    });
    async function test(func) {
        const [a, b, c] = await func();
        console.log(a.toFixed(), b.toFixed(), c.toFixed());
    }
});
```

**Printout:**

```
111 222 333 (this is for the `uint[3] memory arr`)
3 444 555   (this is for the `uint[] memory arr = new uint[](3)`)
```

Comment: Yup. I've never found this documented anywhere, but this has been my experience too.

Comment: Documented at for example https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/miscellaneous.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays  "For dynamic arrays, this slot stores the number of elements in the array"    EDIT: ok the link is about variables in storage and this question is about memory... Anyone can "Edit on Github" to improve the docs

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically-Sized Arrays

Dynamically-sized array `arr` is at slot `0`, and here is stored the size of `arr`. Values are stored starting at the hash of the slot (`0` in this case).

Fixed-Sized Arrays

Fixed-sized array `arr2` is stored at slots `1` and `2`, because the length of the array is `2` (predefined). One slot for each element.

Fixed-sized array `arr3` is located in memory, works similar to `arr2`.

Fixed-sized array `arr4` is located in memory but the behaviour is similar to `arr`. If you pass `0` as a parameter of the function `getFixMemoryArrayElement_2`() you will get the length or `arr4`.

You can use the following code to test in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Array {

    uint[] arr;   // Storage at slot 0
    uint[2] arr2; // Storage at slot 1 and 2

// Dynamic Array Storage

    // Dynamic Array Storage
    function setDynArrayElement() public {
        arr.push(2);
        arr.push(3);
        arr.push(4);
    }

    // Dynamic Array Length
    function getDynArrayLength() public view returns (uint _l) {
        assembly {
            _l := sload(0)
        }
    }

    // Dynamic Array Element
    function getDynElement(uint i) public view returns (uint _x) {
        assembly {
            _x := sload(add(keccak256(sload(0), 32),i))
        }
    }

// Fixed Array Storage

    // Fixed Array Storage
    function setFixnArrayElement() public {
        arr2[0]= 5;
        arr2[1]= 6;
    }

    // Fixed Array Element
    function getFixElement() public view returns (uint _value1, uint _value2) {
        assembly {
            _value1 := sload(1)
            _value2 := sload(2)
        }
    }

// Fixed Array Memory

    // Fixed Array Memory
    function getFixMemoryArrayElement(uint i) public pure returns (uint _l) {
        uint[2] memory arr3;
        arr3[0] = 7;
        arr3[1] = 8;
        assembly {
            _l := mload(add(arr3,mul(i,0x20)))
        }
    }

    function getFixMemoryArrayLen() public pure returns (uint _l) {
        uint[] memory arr4 = new uint[](10);
        assembly {
            _l := mload(arr4)
        }
    }
    function getFixMemoryArrayElement_2(uint i) public pure returns (uint _l) {
        uint[] memory arr4 = new uint[](5);
        arr4[0] = 9;
        arr4[1] = 10;
        assembly {
            _l := mload(add(arr4,mul(i,0x20)))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're answering as though the arrays are in storage, but they're in memory.

Comment: @smarx Are you saying for `arr`and `arr2`? They are not located in storage?

Comment: Yes, in your code, `arr` and `arr2` are located in storage. But the original question was about memory.

Comment: @smarx Oh yes, that's because the question was edited while I was sending the answer.

Comment: Ah! That explains it. :-)

Comment: Interesting point, you can still access the length of a fixed memory array without using a constructor, e.g. `uint[2] memory arr3;`, with the expression `arr3.length`. The length comes from contract bytecode in this case and seems to render the call to `new` fixed array unnecessary and slightly more expensive.